# Wordpress Fotomoto [gallery] lightbox jquery plugin? Anyone know of one that works?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, gallery, photo

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask but I figured you might know.
I'm using the Fotomoto plugin on my site for selling art prints, but I have an issue with finding a plugin that works. I want to use the [gallery] wordpress shortcode with it.

Every wordpress plugin I've tried either doesn't work at all or makes the buttons all disappear. The only one which displays the buttons is simple galleria, but this has broken as it doesn't go straight to the photo when clicked on.
http://artygirl.co.uk/prints/

I've tried all the recommended plugins with no luck
http://support.fotomoto.com/customer/portal/articles/7452-what-scripts-and-libraries-does-fotomoto-support-

shadowbox
lightbox gallery
dm albums
Fancybox
Galleria Galleria
LightBox Plus
Slimbox
Thickbox
prettyPhoto

Anyone know of a good wordpress plugin that works or can fix "Simple Galleria"?
If you can fix this I'll write a blog post about it and give credit and a link back to your site on my site.

Thanks for all your help
Judith

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-galleria-for-wordpress/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fotomoto/

Comment: In order to link thumbnails to image files you need to check `Image File` for `Link thumbnails to` under `Gallery Settings` in the gallery tab of media popup before inserting the gallery shortcode.

Comment: Thanks Zlatev , Unfortunately that doesn't work. I think it might be to do with "simple galleria plugin" php that makes it go to the first photo, but I don't have the knowledge to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

All of the plugins listed on [this page](http://support.fotomoto.com/customer/portal/articles/7452-what-scripts-libraries-and-plugins-does-fotomoto-support)
should work nicely. What I'd suggest you do is pick the plugin from the list that you like best, and if you're having trouble with things not working, just [contact us at Fotomoto Support](http://support.fotomoto.com/customer/portal/emails/new).

I hope that helps and kind regards,

Derek from Fotomoto